# How can I know which process is using the keyboard to input in windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, winapi, keyboard

How can I know which process is using the keyboard to input in windows 10 ?

Comment: See __Keyboard Focus and Activation__ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input  Also what have you tried / researched so far please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

To obtain a window handle to to the foreground window (which is the window on which the user is currently working, and to which the operating system sends all keyboard input), you can use the function [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow).

To get the process ID of the thread that created that window, you can use the function [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid).

The following console program will print, in intervals of 5 seconds, the value of the handle of the foreground window, and the Thread and Process ID that created that window.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    HWND hWnd;
    DWORD dwTID, dwPID;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        dwTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &dwPID );

        printf(
            "Handle of current foreground window: %p\n"
            "That window was created by:\n"
            "Thread ID: %u\n"
            "Process ID: %u\n",
            hWnd, dwTID, dwPID 
        );
        fflush( stdout );

        Sleep( 5000 );

        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```